How to know which configuration my code use in nacos?
The company project has more than 15 configurations in Nacos. In the code, somewhere uses a property from one of these configurations. I want to know which configuration this property comes from.
Example config
a-dal-test.yml
b-dal-test.yml
c-dal-test.yml
a-core-test.yml

The application loads most of the configurations. Now, if I want to know where a particular property comes from, it will take too much time.
Example code
    @DS('A') //This is loaded by configuration in nacos. maybe a-dal-test.yml
    public class AServiceImpl implement AService{
    private void MethodA(){
    }
    }

I want to know name of the specific configuration file which my code use.
